# Why is "Ask Question" retaining my entries after I navigate away?

Tags: discussion, bug

Why is "Ask Question" retaining my entries after I navigate away?  There is no `cancel` so navigating away is the only means, and after I do so I do *not* want to see what I had previously typed in if I'm starting a new question.

Making things worse, after encountering this behavior the first time, I cleared the title and body fields then navigated away *without* being nagged.  But still I come back to "Ask Question" and my previously entered title and body get pre-populated.  This is a negative user experience for me: now I have to clear those fields a *second* time before proceeding.

Comment: Press the "discard" button near the "post your question" button.

Comment: Also on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107321/248731

Comment: Discard?  Really?  Why the divergence from the standard "Cancel" (which I did a search for in the page)  Thanks though!

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I think that's to make it clear that you aren't just not posting the question, but also deleting your inputs so far.